# Proper design of Java Classes

Tags: java, class, oop

My question is should I make `counterbore` (a recessed hole in a plate) a property of `plate` or should `counterbore` be a property of `joint`

I have the following classes for an engineering analysis program:

```
Plate
Bolt
Washer
Nut 
Material
Coating
```

I then have classes that represent various Joints

```
TappedJoint (a joint were the bolt is threaded into the bottom plate) will have:
  Plate topPlate
  Plate bottomPlate
  Bolt bolt
  Washer topWasher

BoltedJoint
  Plate topPlate
  Plate bottomPlate
  Bolt bolt
  Nut nut
  Washer topWasher
  Washer bottomWasher
```

The counterbore is only applicable on the `topPlate` but I need to do validation that the user enters a plate thickness greater than the depth of the counterbore. Do I just set counterbore to null in the bottomPlate or is it better to put the counterbore property in the joint class? Or perhaps I should be using some other pattern such as subclasses?

Coating and Material I add as property to each part because it would be too verbose to add to a joint i.e.:

```
  BoltedJoint
    Plate topPlate
    Plate bottomPlate    
    Coating topPlateTopSurface
    Coating topPlateBottomSurface
    Coating bottomPlateTopSurface ...etc
```

I can probably get it to work with either scenario but perhaps their is better design?

Comment: Does the Plate instance need to know about its own counter bore, or not?  There are actually two counter bore validations needed: the bottom plate should have no counter bore.  This seems to imply that a Plate would need to know how it was being used to know what validations to run.  Starts to get ugly, even with a TopPlate and BottomPlate class.

Comment: I'm thinking no, because from within the joint instance each object can have reference to each other

Answer (score 0):

I think if you make `counterbore`  as property of the `Joint` then both `Plate` and `Bolt` can access the property specific to each `Joint`. That way, Bolt need not to access the Plate object for finding the holes.

Comment: well the thing is, the hole_diameter property is on the plate, because both top and bottom plate must have a hole for the bolt shank.  The counterbore is only on the top plate and is used to recess the head of the bolt.

Comment: If the `counterbore` is used only for top plates then having it in `Plate` could be confusing.

Comment: not sure if we are on the same page.  The through hole diameter is a property of both the top and bottom plate.  The counterbore is an additional hole part way through just the top plate.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterbore#/media/File:Countersunk_and_counterbored_holes_cross-section.png.  Perhaps we are, I just can't tell :)

Comment: hmm... I've been reading and rereading your post and you got me thinking, perhaps the counterbore property goes on the Bolt Object.  Then in other Classes which utilize various properties, I can access with getBolt().getCounterbore().

Comment: The `counterbore` is property is `Joint` because if it is property of either `Bolt` or `Plate` then your `Joint` always need to verify that whether the `Bolt` and `Plate` fit the `counterbore`. So if it is part of `Joint` then consider it as your performing a hole in the top `Plate` which is size of `Bolt`, defined by `counterbore` property in `Joint` itself. After many random thoughts, this one was most convincing to me. I hope it will make sense to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the context correctly, `counterBore` is something the `Joint` requires of its `topPlate`. In that case it should be a property of `Joint` (maybe taken from `Bolt` or whatever dictates it) and the `Joint` should refuse a `topPlate` if it doesn't have sufficient thickness.

If `counterBore` was a physical property of `Plate` (i.e. the `Plate` actually had a drilled counterbore), then it should also be a property of `Plate`. But `Joint` would still have it as a requirement for its `topPlate`.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: In real life, yes the top plate could be counterbored.  I'm trying to reuse the plate object for both the top and bottom plate in a joint.

Comment: @jeff I should rephrase - do you need to *use* the fact that a plate is counterbored or do you just want to check its thickness to ensure it's enough? In the latter case I'd suggest that `Joint` has a `requiredCounterBore` property and compares that to thickness of `topPlate` during validation.

Comment: other classes utilize the counterbore information.  So one class might be performing some engineering calculations and may need the thickness of the top and bottom plate, the length of the bolt and the depth of the couterbore.  I'll instantiate that class setting properties for bolt, plate1, plate2, topWasher, etc..